# Is a real shark used or is it just computerised?

Tags: film-techniques, props, jaws

Can any one tell me, is the shark in "Jaws" real or just computerized?

When I saw that movie I got confused. I have also seen *Jaws 2*.

Comment: No computer graphics at that time. At least none advanced enough for something like this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Three mechanical sharks were built**, all nicknamed *"Bruce"*, after Spielberg's lawyer.

[image: Jaws] <sup>[[Source]](http://www.lassothemovies.com/jaws-1975-afi-100-days-100-movies-56/)</sup>

**[How Steven Spielberg's Malfunctioning Sharks Transformed the Movie Business](http://mentalfloss.com/article/31105/how-steven-spielbergs-malfunctioning-sharks-transformed-movie-business)**

> **Producers wanted Spielberg to hire someone to train a great white** — an impossibility.
>
> The director toyed with rubber props before ultimately **deciding the only real answer was to build a remote-controlled mega-shark—a 25-footer that could swim, leap in the air, and munch on human prey.**
>
> **Every special effects company in Hollywood called the task impossible. Undeterred, Spielberg lured effects guru [Bob Mattey](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0559871/) out of retirement.** Famous for designing the giant squid in the 1954 film [*20,000 Leagues Under the Sea*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046672/), Mattey assured the director he could build the perfect monster.

The mechanical nature of the shark caused some problems, which actually changed Spielbergs approach to the movie.

> When Bob Mattey finally delivered Bruce, Spielberg began to panic.
>
> On its first day on the job, **the shark promptly sank to the bottom of Nantucket Sound**. Within a week, **saltwater had eroded Bruce’s electric motor**, and he had to be refitted with a system of pneumatic hoses. **Every night, Bruce also had to be drained, scrubbed, and repainted.**
>
> Even by diva standards, Bruce was high-maintenance.

Spielberg also [called the shark](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073195/trivia?item=tr0776922) ***"the great white turd"***.

> - ***“I had no choice but to figure out how to tell the story without the shark,”*** Spielberg said. *“So I just went back to Alfred Hitchcock: ‘**What would Hitchcock do** in a situation like this?’ ... **It’s what we don’t see which is truly frightening**.”*
>
> The idea of the unseen enemy completely changed the film’s direction.

---

**[Hunting Bruce, Or, On The Trail Of The 'Jaws' Shark](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=127370664)**

> **Bruce the mechanical shark had a dirty little secret: It didn't work very well.**
>
> Stories abound of the animatronic shark stalling the moment it hit water and sinking to the seafloor. In fact, **the finicky mechanics ended up pushing the film both over budget and over schedule.**

As it turns out, there is actually a fourth Bruce.

> ... **this fourth shark was never used in the film**, but it does appear to have been cast from the original Bruce mold at the time of the film.
>
> **It was made for use at the Universal Studios Theme Park in Hollywood**, where it hung by its tail from 1975 to 1990.

Comment: Fun fact: the shark in `Finding Nemo` is named Bruce in reference to the Jaws shark.

Answer (score 18):

Most of the scenes feature a mechanical shark.

[image: mechanical shark (source: Wikipedia)]

Some [footage of a real shark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaws_%28film%29#Filming) was also used:

> Footage of real sharks was shot by Ron and Valerie Taylor in the waters off Australia, with a smaller-framed actor in a miniature shark cage to create the illusion that the sharks were enormous.

Computer-generated imagery was not used - Jaws was released in 1975, computers were much less powerful back then.

Comment: yeah I was in the process of answering too but when i saw this, I decided to concede :) They used 3 animatronic sharks, take a look at this: http://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2010/0618/Jaws-35th-anniversary-Top-7-animatronic-monsters/Jaws

Comment: There is a lot of documentary on the subject out there, as this was quite revolutionary when Spielberg filmed this. The sharks *realy did* scare movie goers the world over, lol! Today we'd look at it and laugh ... Kind of :-)